# migration- except home page all pages redirecting to old domain

Tags: database, migration

we are migrating from one domain to another domain.

usually we will foloow the procedure of

"open the database file in notepadd++ software and find and replace

old-doamin-name to new-domain-name.

but as the database file size is 1000mb, we can not able to do in notepad++

we change the base urls in core_config_data table.

but now only home page is working the new domain but rest of the other pages is still

redirecting to old domain.

so is there any way in phpmyadmin or through ssh, we can change the old doamin name to new domain name in all places

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally all you need to do is to log in to your database and update the base urls

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://newdomain.com/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; 
update core_config_data set value = 'http://newdomain.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Then clear cache.

If you are still having issues trying log in to the admin and reindex or reindex using the [command line](https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/)

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

You could also using `sed` to find and replace see [How can I replace a string in a file(s)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)?

Comment: i updated in core_config_data before , but still i am facing the issue after clearing cache. even admin panel is redirecting to old domain.

Comment: ssh into the server and try reindex. Also try open the site in a "new incognito view" to make sure it bot browser cache

Comment: i will try the above command

Comment: i used ssh : "i am facing this error : could not open input file"

Comment: `cd` to your `[webroot]` then `php  shell/indexer.php  --reindexall`

Comment: Does not work. I did all what you said and nothing.

Comment: @Kornel... did you clear Magento cache and try in incognito?